# Maven pom load error in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have installed the lastest STS 3.8.1 and created a sample Spring starter project but I have landed up with error below:

> Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out pom.xml /demo   line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem

Comment: Looks like you have a network problem. Have you tried retrying the maven commands, and/or trying from the terminal?

Comment: No I didn't tried with maven commands and can you please let me know what are u referring. Regarding the network I am using the manual proxy settings which has been already taken care.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do a "Maven -> Update Project" and check the "Force Update of Releases/Snapshots" in those situations. It re-downloads those dependencies.

Comment: Yes, and if that still doesn't help a more drastic measure of deleting the local maven cache itself at `~/.m2/repository` can also be tried. To avoid redownloading too much stuff, you can also just delete small section of the repo (e.g. the subdirectory for just the group id of the troublesome artifact).